# SQLAlchemy how join if not already joined

Tags: join, sqlalchemy

In some different situations in a request life cycle on my project, joining to some other tables may be required for the main `query` of that request. How can I join with a table if it was not already joined with that? In the other word I need some methods like this:

> context.query = context.query.join_if_not_already_joined(table2)